# Thevenin equivalent of mosfet

Tags: mosfet

[image]

Can someone explain to me how the author derived that the Vt thevenin equivalent voltage was Vin1. It is looking into the source of M1 which is a VCCS. The thevenin resistance makes sense,

Here is what I have
[image]

Comment: M1 is a source follower and if RS approaches infinity the voltage gain becomes equal to one thus, Vth = Vin. And Rth = 1/gm (output resistance of a source follower)

Comment: @G36 I understand but just looking at the small signal model that I have drawn looking into the source of M1 and trying to measure the open circuit thevenin voltage, it won't give me Vin1.

Comment: Why not? Notice that gm*Vgs must be zero (id = 0A open circuit), right? This means that Vgs is 0 as well so, Vt = Vin

Comment: You can try to use the T-model instead to is it better https://engineering.purdue.edu/wcchew/ece255s18/ece%20255%20s18%20latex%20pdf%20files/ece255Lecture_15_Mar6_MOSFET_Small_Signals.pdf (figure 7)

Comment: @G36 That makes, you're right. The only solution in this case is that ID = 0A, thus Vt = Vin. It's clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M1 is operating as a source follower (even though it has a drain resistor). In this configuration the ideal output voltage from the source (\$V_T\$) is the gate voltage (\$V_{in1}\$). However, it's not an accurate approximation if you want my opinion.

It's a more accurate approximation if BJTs were used but, MOSFETs are a bit hit and miss in this respect and, \$V_T\$ could be more like \$\frac{V_{in1}}{2}\$ or somewhere in between.

Answer (score 0):

Find the current from the drain of m1, this could be modeled as a current source. Then convert the current source to a voltage source with series resistance

Comment: I have added an extra image in my original post. How do I get the voltage at the source of M1?